# drop down symbol doesnt show permanently in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

I am trying to make a drop down in excel file.
which works just fine

but it shows like this

1 : image when cell is not selected

[image: image when cell is not selected]

and when I select the cell it shows like this

2 : image when cell is selected

[image: image when cell is selected]

i want this drop down arrow to be shown permanently so the user knows the particular cell is drop down

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using colour scheme to indicate to a user where input is required.

There is another way, but it won't always be a good solution. Using your image above, highlight B2:B5 and right click>format cells>protection> *uncheck* "Locked"

Press OK and then protect the sheet. Do this by the Review tab on the ribbon>Protect Sheet and ensure that the **only** checkbox that is ticked is "Select unlocked cells"

This will ensure that, while protected, the user is only able to select the input cells B2:B5 and thus, one of them will always be active and show the dropdown icon

Comment: but the form has other fields also so cant hold the user to one drop down

Comment: You can unlock all fields that are subject to user input, which has the advantage of allowing the user to tab through the input fields. However, I would just colour code them.

Answer (score 1):

Put a Combo Box (DEVELOPER > Controls - Insert, Form Controls) underneath the validation arrow:

[image: SO25883482 example]